# having issues recording error in export-csv

Tags: powershell

I have powershell script to pull down hotfixID, installedon, lastbootuptime and freespace in C drive. (I googled around and changed couple of things I need.) when the Pc is not reachable it will

```
Write-Warning "$_ cannot be reached, skipping."
```

I also want to capture the computer name of the failed PC to my CSV. I tried

```
| Export-Csv C:\test\computerDetails.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

or append but seems like its not working. can someone please help? below is my whole script.

```
(Get-Content C:\test\serverlist.txt).Trim() | ForEach {

    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet) 
    {

        $update = Get-CimInstance Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ComputerName $_ | Sort-Object InstalledOn -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
        $os = Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $_
        $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $_ -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"

        $props = @{
            ComputerName = $_
            HotFixID = $update.HotFixID
            InstalledOn = $update.InstalledOn
            lastbootuptime = $os.LastBootUpTime
            FreeSpace_GB = $disk.FreeSpace / 1GB
        }
        New-Object PsObject -Property $props
    } 
    Else {
           Write-Warning "$_ cannot be reached, skipping." | Export-Csv C:\test\computerDetails.csv -NoTypeInformation
                }

} | Sort ComputerName |
        Select ComputerName,HotFixID,InstalledOn,lastbootuptime,FreeSpace_GB |
            Export-Csv C:\test\computerDetails.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I assume it is coming out with Length and the numbers, that is because you are exporting a string to a CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem with adding it to the CSV is that it is a string. If you treat the erroneous machines the same as successful ones, then you can throw them in the same CSV.

I have added an `ArrayList` there as the storage variable and then for each computer it creates a temp `PSObject` to store your results in, overwriting the variable each loop but not before dumping the variable into the `ArrayList` for export at the end.

```
$Errors = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
(Get-Content C:\test\serverlist.txt).Trim() | ForEach {
    $Temp = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $update = Get-CimInstance Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ComputerName $_ | Sort-Object InstalledOn -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
        $os = Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $_
        $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $_ -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"

        $props = [ordered]@{
            ComputerName   = $_
            HotFixID       = $update.HotFixID
            InstalledOn    = $update.InstalledOn
            lastbootuptime = $os.LastBootUpTime
            FreeSpace_GB   = $disk.FreeSpace / 1GB
            Error          = "Success"
        }
        $Temp | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $props -TypeName temp
    } Else {
        $props = [ordered]@{
            ComputerName   = $_
            Error          = "Cannot be reached"
        }
        $Temp | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $props -TypeName temp
        Write-Warning "$_ cannot be reached, skipping."
    }
    $Errors.Add($Temp) > $null
}
 $Errors | Export-Csv C:\temp\computerDetails.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: Hey Drew this works like a charm. another question, some how my script gives
below error when I have lots of computer(this worked fine when I test with 3 PC).

Sort-Object : Exception getting "InstalledOn": "Exception calling "Parse" with "2" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.""
At C:\test\updatereport.ps1:5 char:80
+ ... eering -ComputerName $_ | Sort-Object InstalledOn -Descending | Selec ...
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (Win32_QuickFixE...kInEffect =

Comment: Check the individual machines throwing the error, you may find it is a null field or a weird date.
If commands work for some machines but not other, check the expected output and troubleshoot as needed.